# Hamming distance

Tags: error-correcting-codes

I have some difficulties in computing Hamming distance in following example:

11100000
00011100
10010010
01001001

I know the definition of Hamming distance (in case of two codewords)
but how to proceed in above example.
Can someone shed some light on how to compute d_min in above example?

Regards

Comment: What is d_min? If it's just the minimum Hamming distance between any pair of codewords, then you just need to compute all the distances and choose the smallest.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Denote the codewords as $a_1,...a_4$. Remember that the hamming distance is the number of different bits between two codewords.

1. $d(a_1,a_2) = 6$
2. $d(a_1,a_3) = 4$
3. $d(a_1,a_4) = 4$
4. $d(a_2,a_3) = 4$
5. $d(a_2,a_4) = 4$
6. $d(a_3,a_4) = 6$

Thus $d=4$.